# Google App Engine equivalent VPC Peering with MongoDB Atlas

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, vpc, mongodb-atlas

I find it odd that it's common to host your DB miles away from your webserver, which makes little sense to me.

Also, the cost of serving data from your DBaaS to your PaaS web service and back, then from the web service to the end user, means you're paying more than double as much.

Ideally, I would want a PaaS that scales really well and can host my database and web in the same region at least, while also minimizing costs.

I see many articles on how to do this the AWS way, with VPC Peering. While GCP has VPC also, I have not figured out how I can enable Google App Engine to exist in the same private cloud as a GCP hosted MongoDB Atlas cluster.

Is it possible? If so, how?

If the answer is "just use AWS then", unfortunately AWS does not have the desired PaaS per say, other than another 3rd party like Heroku, that then won't do VPC Peering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

VPC peering is now available for GCP and Azure as well.

---

**Original post:**

It is not possible to have Google App Engine and a GCP hosted MongoDB Atlas cluster in the same Virtual Private Cloud.

Since they are different projects each one is in a different Virtual Private Cloud. The only way for the two VPCs to communicate internally would be VPC Peering, which is not currently supported. So the only way for them to communicate is publicly, by adding the IP addresses of the GCP services in the whitelist of the Atlas project.

[Atlas VPC Peering Documentation](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-vpc-peering/):

> Atlas does not support VPC Peering for clusters deployed on Google
>   Cloud Platform. For Atlas clusters deployed on GCP add the IP addresses of your GCP services to Atlas project IP whitelist to grant those services access to the cluster.

Choose the region of your MongoDB Atlas cluster to be the same as your Google App Engine application. Having the services in the same region minimizes latency and network costs.

Comment: So then best I go with AWS on this one, as the VPC Peering has a massive benefit (both cost and speed).

Comment: VPC Peering has been enabled for Azure and GCP